# Does Kawartha Lakes/Peterborough County contain any high ground or lookouts?

Tags: hiking, nature-and-wildlife, ontario

Are there any high grounds or scenic lookouts or peaks from which foliage can be viewed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely! Conservation areas often have them. Here's a picture I took in 2010 from a lookout at the [Fleetwood Creek conservation area](http://kawarthaconservation.com/conservation-areas/fleetwood-creek-natural-area) in Kawartha Lakes:

[image]

There are plenty of others in the area. Are you looking to go north or south of Peterborough? Would you like to get a lake involved as well?

The leaves are good right now in this area by the way. I got a gorgeous dose of leaf-peeping just popping out to pick up my veggies from the farm - 5 miles each way along country roads and lots of golds, yellows, and reds on either side of the road and occasionally over it.

Comment: +1. Thank you as always. I answer your questions: I am planning to go north and would love to see the lakes, but should I go south also?

Comment: You can go where you like. I could probably find hundreds of lookouts in the area you've specified. You have to look at some other factors - hotel availability, restaurants, other things to do. You have to make the decision.

Comment: Thanks again. Would you please explain how you `could probably find hundreds of lookouts in the area you've specified`, to help me to accomplish this myself?

Comment: If you have a car, go for a drive. If you have a map, drive towards a conservation area or park. Simply stopping at the top of a hill on a country road will often be very rewarding. Leaf-peeping is not challenging by any means. You get yourself out in the country side on a sunny day and you enjoy it. The nice thing about parks is that you have signs "this way to the lookout" but there are lookouts at the top of almost every hill. On a sideroad it will generally be safe for you to just pull over and enjoy it - don't do so on Highway 115 or Highway 7 though.